# Migrating print drivers between terminal servers

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, terminal-server, drivers, printing

I have two windows 2008 terminal servers. One is existing and has all the necessary print drivers installed. How do I migrate the drivers from one to the other without having to install these manually.

I don't need to migrate the printers, just the drivers so that those connecting through RDP don't get left with the horribly slow Easy Print Driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Have you tried the Windows Print Server Migration wizard/CLI tool?](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722360.aspx)